# Question about prototypal inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, scope

I was reading the AngularJS wiki section about understanding scopes and I had a question in this [part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mNlX.png).

 
Before it is said that when, in the child scope we make an assignment to a primitive property in the parent scope, it hides/shadows the parent scopes property of the same name with the new value.

Why then when we make an assignment, in the child scope, to an array in the parent scope, do we hide/shadow the parent prop, if an array is not a primitive type? Shouldn't it be updated on the parent scope property?

Basically why does an assignment to a new array not cause an update to the parent scope array with the same property name, but creates a new property on the child.

Thanks

Comment: If you modify array object elements in child it will be seen in parent since array reference is the same. If you assign a new array though it won't. Does that help? Question is a bit unclear

Comment: Sorry about the question, I will try and make it clearer.
But about that, shouldn't the parent scope change the reference to the new array?

Comment: No. If you overwrite the original array reference it is lost in parent. If you need to replace an array.... empty the existing one and insert whatever new data you need. The array object reference will remain the same, only the contents will be different

Comment: Ohh okay understood. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: May not need to empty it depending on what you are doing. Methods like splice() can be used to remove an element and keep same array object

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip